# Python : Cubic Spline matching slope at the end point

Tags: python, interpolation

I have 2 arrays representing x,y data of a contour. What I want is to create a spline between a segment/part of these coordinates.
In the example below, it is between index 17 and 22. Assuming there will be indexes before and after the segment end points -- ie: end_points_idx would never be 0 or len(xt), would I be able to place a constraint on the spline to match the gradient of the contour at the segment end points ?

In the below picture highlighted are the area of interest-- here the slope of red curve (interpolated) and blue curve (original) has to match.

[image]

My initial guess was to include the previous and next points when generating the spline so that this constraint is met. For example, instead of making a spline using only xt[start:end], I could use xt[start-1, end+1].

My requirement is to have an interpolate function that allows me to change the number of divisions, and also to parameterize the curve such that something like circle could be interpolated.

Could someone please point me to the right direction ?

My code so far is as follows.

```
import numpy as np
from  scipy.interpolate import interp1d

# xt,yt = np.loadtxt('test.dat', skiprows=0).T

xt = np.array([ 8.453243e-01,  8.253228e-01,  7.833743e-01,  7.365502e-01,
        6.891306e-01,  6.416059e-01,  5.940522e-01,  5.465124e-01,
        4.990289e-01,  4.516513e-01,  4.044349e-01,  3.574415e-01,
        3.107540e-01,  2.644899e-01,  2.188345e-01,  1.742391e-01,
        1.323497e-01,  9.486680e-02,  6.290130e-02,  3.848860e-02,
        2.217660e-02,  1.190140e-02,  5.468900e-03,  1.648900e-03,
       -2.280000e-05,  3.577000e-04,  3.118400e-03,  8.496300e-03,
        1.672160e-02,  2.922920e-02,  4.998550e-02,  8.469840e-02,
        1.292434e-01,  1.744219e-01,  2.194487e-01,  2.651439e-01,
        3.114009e-01,  3.580644e-01,  4.050267e-01,  4.522034e-01,
        4.995318e-01,  5.469606e-01,  5.944399e-01,  6.419280e-01,
        6.893808e-01,  7.367256e-01,  7.834690e-01,  8.253520e-01,
        8.453243e-01])

yt = np.array([ 0.0243156,  0.0270423,  0.0324888,  0.0381673,  0.0435173,
        0.0484963,  0.0530971,  0.0573041,  0.0610846,  0.0643884,
        0.067147 ,  0.0692699,  0.0706418,  0.0711173,  0.0705181,
        0.0686287,  0.0651657,  0.0593667,  0.0510192,  0.0413076,
        0.0321261,  0.024251 ,  0.0174636,  0.0113825,  0.0057938,
        0.0005957, -0.0044695, -0.0088123, -0.0124099, -0.0155856,
       -0.0187322, -0.0222811, -0.0260505, -0.028932 , -0.0302477,
       -0.0302378, -0.0291441, -0.0271504, -0.0244002, -0.0210119,
       -0.0170752, -0.012661 , -0.0078207, -0.0025858,  0.0030262,
        0.0090099,  0.015313 ,  0.0213215,  0.0243156])

end_points_idx = [17, 22]

def interpolate(x, y, n=100):
    i = np.arange(len(x))
    interp_i = np.linspace(i.min(), i.max(), n)

    xi = interp1d(i, x, kind='cubic')(interp_i)
    yi = interp1d(i, y, kind='cubic')(interp_i)

    return xi,yi




segment_x = xt[end_points_idx[0]:end_points_idx[1]+1]
segment_y = yt[end_points_idx[0]:end_points_idx[1]+1]

vort_x, vort_y = interpolate(segment_x, segment_y, n=5)
```